# How do I output a collection of objects with JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

Not able to generate the required XML from the java class as expected.

This is a class defining the property of zoo

```
**//Modal Class**
 public class Zoo 
{
private String name;
private String place;
    //Getters Setters

}
```

Action class with list of zoo class to be in XML

**//Action Class with multiple objects of zoo class**

```
@ManagedBean
@XmlRootElement
public @SessionScoped class zoos implements Serializable {
   private String name;
   private String place;
   private static final ArrayList<Zoo> zoo_list
= new ArrayList<Zoo>();

    @XmlElement
public ArrayList<Zoo> getZoo_list()
{
  return zoo_list;

}
    public void xmleg()
    {

        File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");   
        for(Zoo add: zoo_list)
        {
         try 
         {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Zoos.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();


            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);


            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<Zoo>(new QName("","Zoo"),zoo.class,add),file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<Zoo>(new QName("","Zoo"),zoo.class,add),System.out);

              } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
              }
         }
        }
```

Output that is generated is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<zoo>
    <linkId>0</linkId>
    <name>gfdsgdgtretr</name>
    <place>gdfg</place>
</zoo>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<zoo>
   <linkId>0</linkId>
    <name>gfdsgdgtretr</name>
    <place>gdfg</place>
</zoo>
```

**But the Expected Output should be:**

```
 <zoos>
   <zoo>
     <linkId>0</linkId>
     <name>gfdsgdgtretr</name>
     <place>gdfg</place>
  </zoo>
  <zoo>
    <linkId>0</linkId>
    <name>gfdsgdgtretr</name>
    <place>gdfg</place>
  </zoo>     
  </zoos>
```

Have tried with the @XMLElementWrapper annotation as well but its not working too.Have gone through many tutorials but didnt find the solution.

Comment: private static final ArrayList<zoo> zoo_list
= new ArrayList<zoo>(); - is this a typo? Your class is Zoo.

Comment: we have the right code.it is just a typing mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I just reread your question and you already have the `Zoos` class.  You should be marshalling the instance of that instead of the individual items from the `zoo_list` property.  You can change the element name that property maps to with the `@XmlElement` annotation.

```
@XmlElement(name="zoo")
public ArrayList<Zoo> getZoo_list()
```

---

JAXB (JSR-222) implementations require a root objject.  The easiest thing to do is create an object called `Zoos` that holds onto the list of `Zoo` objects and marshal that.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Zoos {

    private List<Zoo> zoo;

    public List<Zoo> getZoo() {
        return zoo;
    }

    public void setZoo(List<Zoo> zoo) {
        this.zoo = zoo;
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you could create a `FileWriter` for the `File`.  Then you could write the start element yourself.  Then use JAXB to marshal each of the `Zoo` instances to the `FileWriter` (you will need to leverage the following property to have JAXB exclude the XML header.

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
```

Finally you need to close the root element.

Comment: @user2224083 - If this answer solved your issue you can click the checkmark icon next to the answer to mark the question resolved.